Disable "Create Account" in Amplify Gen 2 Congito Resource
In order to jumpstart a new app, I am following the Amplify Gen 2 tutorial.  The instructions for adding authentication are pretty close to what I need, but I want to create my accounts manually on the backend instead of self-registration
Is there a way to disable the "Create Account" portion of the login widget?

Thanks!

The Authenticator has an option to hide the sign up page including the Create Account tab.
<Authenticator hideSignUp />


For more detail, refer Amplify documentation - Hide Sign Up

That works for the UI!  What about securing the cognito against attack?  I did that manually, but is there a way to do it within my amplify workspace since the resource was created by amplify?
